# Multiple variable assignment showing unexpected value

Tags: python

I have these 5 array initialized to empty value by using multiple assignment. I am trying to add a different value in each of those arrays. However it seems all arrays value are showing same values. How is this possible?

Code

```
arr1=arr2=arr3=arr4=arr5=[]

def test(arr,fruit):
arr.append(fruit)

test(arr1, "Apple")
test(arr2, "Anar")
test(arr3, "Orange")
test(arr4, "Fig")

print(arr1)
print(arr2)
print(arr3)
print(arr4)
```

Output

```
['Apple', 'Anar', 'Orange', 'Fig']
['Apple', 'Anar', 'Orange', 'Fig']
['Apple', 'Anar', 'Orange', 'Fig']
['Apple', 'Anar', 'Orange', 'Fig']
```

Comment: You assigned one list to five variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because all those variables point to the same array. Instead you want to initialize each one on separate lines:

```
arr1 = []
arr2 = []
arr3 = []
arr4 = []
```

Comment: I understand initializing on separate line will work, but if I initialize on same line, then why won't it create a five separate arrays?

Comment: @vegabond because it's similar to doing `arr1=[]` and then doing `arr2=arr1`, esentially passing the reference of the actual list from arr1 to arr2, resulting in both of the variables pointing to the same list/memory. That's just how Python is built.

Comment: @vegabond You explicitly set all the variables to the same object. Why are you surprised that they're all referring to the same object?

Comment: A simple test to check that they all point to the same object is by calling `id(arr1)` and `id(arr2)` and you will see that they are identical.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach is using list comprehension to do multiple assignment without creating reference to the same list as

```
arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5 = [[] for _ in range(5)]
```